# In memory local variables (javascript), OAuth token storage, and XSS

Tags: xss, javascript, oauth2, openid-connect

Quoting from a long-dead Auth0 forum post: https://community.auth0.com/t/why-is-storing-tokens-in-memory-recommended/17742

> "Any values stored in memory are still vulnerable to XSS attacks since
> they’re accessible by JavaScript. Agreed?
>
> Agreed. The main difference is that localStorage makes it even easier
> to enumerate the contents. The point of this is just to avoid a brute
> force XSS attack from being able to dump your localStorage somewhere
> else that could allow it to be used for nefarious purposes. Storing in
> memory just makes it so someone has to go through the extra effort of
> targeting your app specifically. But yes, memory is still susceptible
> to XSS attacks."

I don't get it.

My Javascript is rusty, but taking a stab at knocking out a quick redirect_uri implementation:

**`https://localhost/redirect.html#access_token=123`**

```
<script>
(function () {
    const match = RegExp('[#&]access_token=([^&]*)').exec(window.location.hash);
    const token = match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));

    APICaller(token);
})();
</script>
```

**my library.js**

```
function APICaller(token) {

   var private_static_token = token; // HOW CAN XSS GET HOLD OF THIS?

   APICaller.overlySimpleGet = async function(url) {
     return fetch(encodeURI(url), {
       method: 'GET',
         headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + private_static_token },
       })
       .then(response => response.json());
   }
}
```

**app code (imports library.js)**

```
APICaller.overlySimpleGet("https://localhost/apiresponse.json")
   .then((json) => console.log(json));
```

Given the initial statement in the forum post:

> "Storing in memory just makes it so someone has to go through the
> extra effort of targeting your app specifically. But yes, memory is
> still susceptible to XSS attacks"

*How is the value of `private_static_token` vulnerable to XSS?*

Equally, if you have an XSS vulnerability in your redirect_uri page, then it would seem that a much simpler option for the attacker would be just to read the token when the page loads before it even got to your local variable.
And that could be an untargeted attack.

Side note:

It seems to me that there is really only one good method for token storage - a httponly/secure/samesite=strict cookie with CSRF protection, which only works if you have a backend.

The other browser storage options can all, with varying degrees of effort, be compromised by XSS, so you better have a strict Content Security Policy in place for those.
(This makes me wonder why OAuth implicit flows don't support cookies as well as headers, but no doubt there is a good/practical reason I can't think of atm.)

Edit: It occurred to me later that a httpOnly cookie is also partly vulnerable to XSS. While it does have the benefit of preventing the token from being stolen, it does not prevent an injected script in the page from sending ajax requests to your backend (a targeted attack). So given that you still must protect against XSS (but now also the extra effort of protecting against XSRF too), then you have to decide if the addition of token-stealing protection is sufficient to warrant the extra implementation effort of XSRF protection. If you have a strict CSP, then cookies probably aren't worth the effort, which may be why the OAuth implicit flows don't bother with them.

Comment: in this case, i could clobber fetch(), decodeURIComponent(), or APICaller / its methods to get your secret. you could Object.freeze your instance, which helps, but you still need to guarantee the on and off ramps to your secure highway are built by the highway dept. It also unclear why the attacker can't see location.hash, but i point out the less obvious vectors.